# MASM x64 calling convention - why does allocstack needed multiple times here?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm, calling-convention

I have the following code I have inherited and am trying to make sense of it.

I get .allocstack 20h -- it's saying allocate stack space for 32 bytes, right?

But why is there allocstack for each register? And if there is then why isn't the last allocstack 8h (because there already 3 allocstacks for 8, so the 32 bytes requirement is fulfilled)?

```
    ; save registers
    push    rax
    .allocstack 8

    push    r10
    .allocstack 8

    push    r11
    .allocstack 8

    sub     rsp, 20h
    .allocstack 20h

    .endprolog

    call    EnterStub

    add     rsp, 20h

    ; restore registers
    pop     r11
    pop     r10
    pop     rax

    ; return
    ret
```

Comment: https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/objfmt-win64-exception.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5btab6c7.aspx), it says:

> .ALLOCSTACK allows ml64.exe users to specify how a frame function
>   unwinds and is only allowed within the prologue, which extends from
>   the PROC FRAME declaration to the .ENDPROLOG directive. These
>   directives do not generate code; they only generate .xdata and .pdata.
>   .ALLOCSTACK should be preceded by instructions that actually implement
>   the actions to be unwound.

The `.allocstack` only describes what is done by the code. As such, the `.allocstack 8` after each `push` is to create the appropriate unwind info (a `push` adjusts `rsp` by 8). The final `.allocstack 20h` describes the `sub rsp, 20h`.

Comment: One more question -- do you know if PROC FRAME ends up creating a call stack frame? I would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: It doesn't create stack frame. You can verify that by asking for a listing or disassembling the resulting file.